# Simulate a click on DBGrid

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-5, zeos

I have done some searching and nothing is working.

Using D5, Zeos and SQLite.

I have a DBGrid and a DataSet (tblBricks) that is Filtered.

In the DBGrid1.OnCellClick Event, I have

```
tblBricks.Refresh;
```

At run-time I can set focus to the appropriate Row in the DBGrid with

```
tblBricks.Locate('Color','Red',[loCaseInsensitive]);
frmMain.DBGridCellClick(Columns[0]);
```

and it focuses the correct Row and Column.

The problem is that the first time I run this application, when the DataSet is Opened, it is set to Filtered:=True; but the display does not yet show as Filtered.

If I click the **already focused** cell in the DBGrid, then it suddenly Filters and correctly displays the results.

How can I simulate a click to the Cell so that the first time through it forces the Filtering or maybe, just force the DataSet to Filter?

Not sure if this is an idiosyncrasy of D5, Zeos, SQLite or a combination.

Thanks

Comment: How do you define the filter now? When do you set the `Filtered` property to `True`?

Comment: My answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15736647/62576

Comment: Ha! LOL. Very funny @Ken it is already set and the thing works fine after that first time through. I can go to another Form and change the DataSet Cursor there and then reset it in the OnClose and the Filtering is shown correctly back on the main Form. It is only on the first time when I run the app.

Comment: @Jach, the defining of the Filter is fine as it works all other times. I have tried setting the True both before and after the tblBricks.Active:=True and same thing. As I mentioned to Ken, it is only on that first time I run the app. Other than that all works as expected. I just wanted to try a forced Click to the focused Cell and see if that resolved the issue. I am happy with brute-force if it works. :)

Comment: If that's the case, you should put it in the AfterOpen event of your dataset.